Has anyone run the Dhrystone MIPS 2.1 benchmark on a stock, 2.8MHz, Apple IIgs?
I can't find any Dhrystone MIPS figures for the Apple IIgs, be it the stock 2.8 MHZ WDC 65C816 variant, or any of the overclocked or accelerator card packing variants. Has anyone tried the benchmark on a stock Apple IIgs, or know of a source, if so what were the numbers?

You can find lots of discussion about dhrystone numbers and accelerators on old comp.sys.apple2 and comp.sys.apple2.gno usenet posts.  Here are some numbers from the accelerator FAQ:
 BenchMark v5.0 results:

 CPU        Stock    TWGS   TWGS   TWGS    ZipGS  ZipGS  ZipGS 
 Version    ROM 01   1.8s   1.8s   1.8s    1.0.2  1.0.2  1.0.2 
 Cache/Spd          32k/15 32k/15 32k/15   64k/?? 64k/?? 64k/?? 
 Clock Spd    2.8     15   13.75   12.5      16     15     14 
           =======  ====== ====== ======   ====== ====== ====== 
 Sieve      410.00   99.00 108.00 117.00    98.00  99.00 110.00 
 String    1151.20  270.00 292.00 303.67   259.00 262.00 282.00 
 Float 1    472.00   92.33  87.00 111.33   123.00 128.00 135.00 
 Float 2   1535.00  317.00 394.00 381.67   395.00 415.00 432.00 
 Fibinacci 2006.00  605.00 634.00 645.33   507.00 523.00 548.00 
 Integer   1553.40  307.00 330.00 346.67   420.00 431.00 443.00

 Dhrystone  236     1136   1063   1000       NA     NA     NA 
     *              1351          1183     1282     NA     NA

* Dhrystone v1.1 re-compiled under ORCA/C v2.0.1 
 

     System Software 5.0 QuickDraw II improvement test:

     Stock //gs:     5648 ticks 
     TWGS 15 MHz:    1332 ticks (over 4x faster than stock) 
 

If you look at the numbers, a 12 MHz or faster TWGS/Zip will make everything 
just about 4x faster than a stock //gs. 
 

Other self reported numbers are fairly consistent, somewhere around 70-90 dhrystones per mhz.  Keep in mind it's just as much a compiler benchmark as a CPU benchmark.  People often didn't report (or know) which compiler was involved.  Dhrystone compiled with ORCA/C 2.0 was 20% faster than with ORCA/C 1.x.
